# Procedure failed due to ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Getting below error while executing in 12c oracle,but it is working fine when it was in oracle 10.2.0.4 :

Procedure proc_up_dts_product_cat_dynsql failed due to ORA-00920: invalid
relational operator
Here is the procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SEAPROB.proc_up_dts_product_cat_dynsql(tablename IN varchar)
AS
dynamicsql varchar(8000);
ID int;
DTS_Segment_op  varchar2(10);
DTS_Segment varchar2(15);
DTS_Segment_where   varchar2(255);
DateEntered_op  varchar2(10);
DateEntered varchar2(30);
DateEntered_where   varchar2(255);
Svc_Name_op varchar2(10);
Svc_Name    varchar2(100);
Svc_Name_where  varchar2(255);
Product_Category    varchar2(75);
Priority    int;
combined_status_where varchar2(255);
refdate date ;
CURSOR PrivCursor
IS
SELECT
ID,
DTS_Segment_op,
Nvl(upper(trim(DTS_Segment)),' '),
DateEntered_op,
CASE WHEN dateentered='%' THEN dateentered
  WHEN dateentered LIKE '%/%/____' THEN To_Char(To_Date(dateentered,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
  WHEN dateentered LIKE '%/%/__' THEN To_Char(To_Date(dateentered,'MM/DD/YY'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
  WHEN dateentered LIKE '''%/%/%'' % ''%/%/%''' THEN ''''||To_Char(To_Date(SubStr(dateentered,InStr(dateentered,'''',1,1)+1,InStr(dateentered,'''',1,2)-InStr(dateentered,'''',1,1)-1),'MM/DD/YY'),'YYYY-MM-DD')||''' and '''||To_Char(To_Date(SubStr(dateentered,InStr(dateentered,'''',1,3)+1,InStr(dateentered,'''',1,4)-InStr(dateentered,'''',1,3)-1),'MM/DD/YY'),'YYYY-MM-DD')||''''
  ELSE dateentered END AS dateentered,
Svc_Name_op,
Nvl(upper(trim(Svc_Name)),' '),
Product_Category,
Priority
FROM tbl_dts_pt_lookup order by priority desc;


BEGIN
refdate := ADD_MONTHS(to_date(SYSDATE,'dd-mon-yy'),-6) ;

OPEN PrivCursor;
-- Loop through all the rows in the tbl_dts_category_lookup table
FETCH PrivCursor
INTO
ID,
DTS_Segment_op,
DTS_Segment,
DateEntered_op,
DateEntered,
Svc_Name_op,
Svc_Name,
Product_Category,
Priority;

WHILE PrivCursor%found

LOOP
-- Create dynamic SQL
--define case statements for where clause components
combined_status_where := ' where (DTS_Cm_DisputeStatus <>'|| '''C''' || ' OR ( DTS_Cm_DisputeStatus='|| '''C''' ||  ' AND DTS_CM_CLOSEDATE >=  '''||refdate||'''))' ;
dts_segment_where := case when dts_segment='%' then ' and 1=1' else ' and NVL(trim(Replace(Upper(segment),chr(0),''' || ''')),''' || ' '') ' || dts_segment_op || ' ''' || dts_segment || '''' end;
svc_name_where := case when svc_name='%' then ' and 1=1' else ' and NVL(trim(Replace(Upper(dts_cm_servicename),chr(0),''' || ''')),''' || ' '') ' || svc_name_op || ' ''' || svc_name || '''' end ;
dateentered_where := case when dateentered='%' then ' and 1=1'
                                 when dateentered_op='between' then ' and TO_CHAR(dts_cm_dateentered,''YYYY-MM-DD'') between ' || dateentered
                                 else ' and TO_CHAR(dts_cm_dateentered,''YYYY-MM-DD'') ' || dateentered_op || ' ''' || dateentered || '''' end ;

dynamicsql := 'update '||tablename||' set product_cat_id=' || cast(id as varchar) ||', product_category =''' || product_category || '''';
--add where clause
dynamicsql := dynamicsql || combined_status_where || dts_segment_where || dateentered_where || svc_name_where;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dynamicsql;
COMMIT;

FETCH PrivCursor
INTO
ID,
DTS_Segment_op,
DTS_Segment,
DateEntered_op,
DateEntered,
Svc_Name_op,
Svc_Name,
Product_Category,
Priority;

END LOOP;
CLOSE PrivCursor;


EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Procedure proc_up_dts_product_cat_dynsql failed due to '||SQLERRM);
END proc_up_dts_product_cat_dynsql;
/
```

Comment: `EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` **First and foremost, remove this bug from your code**. And then use `SHOW ERRORS` to get the full error stack with exact line number. If it is a run time error, then copy paste your SQL*Plus session and edit your question to add the details.

Comment: @LalitKumarB why consider `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN`.. is a bug ?

Comment: @Moudiz Just google `WHEN OTHERS Oracle bug`. Else, read my article, [**WHEN OTHERS – A bug**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/05/02/when-others-then-null-a-bug/) Some other useful articles http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/WHEN_OTHERS and this one by **Thomas Kyte** http://tkyte.blogspot.in/2012/05/pokemon-and-when-others.html and this too https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1155066278457 Bottomline "**A when others is almost always a BUG unless it is immediately followed by a RAISE.**"

Comment: @Bhuvananagulan Could you comment `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement and add `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(dynamicsql);` before it and re-execute in SQL*Plus. Make sure you do `set serveroutput on` before executing the procedure.

Comment: tried executing without DBMS_OUTPUT line got error in below lines :dynamicsql := 'update '||tablename||' set product_cat_id=' || cast(id as varchar) ||', product_category =''' || product_category || '''';
--add where clause
dynamicsql := dynamicsql || combined_status_where || dts_segment_where || dateentered_where || svc_name_where;

Comment: dynamicsql := 'update '||tablename||' set product_cat_id=' || cast(id as varchar) ||', product_category =''' || product_category || '''';
--add where clause
dynamicsql := dynamicsql || combined_status_where || dts_segment_where || dateentered_where || svc_name_where;

Answer (score 3):

The database hurls `ORA-00920: invalid relational operator` when we submit a SQL statement with a syntax error in a WHERE clause.  Usually it's a typo.  This is extremely easy to do in dynamic SQL, because we cannot see the whole statement except at run time.

You haven't posted the generated update statement.  Well you can't, as your exception handling doesn't display it.  Pro tip: when working with dynamic SQL *always log or display the generated statement*, in the exception block if nowhere else:

```
dbms_output.put_line('generated statement:'|| dynamicsql);
```

So this is just a guess but this line looks suspicious ...

```
 when dateentered_op='between' then ' and TO_CHAR(dts_cm_dateentered,''YYYY-MM-DD'') between ' || dateentered
```

... because it appears to generate a BETWEEN statement with no AND clause.  The BETWEEN operator requires two bounds.

But it could be many things.  You may be running with an unusual combination of parameters which generates an invalid statement.  You need better logging.